# What’s the meaning of ‘we will emerge’?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, pronouns

One of ‘we’ is under his Invisibility Cloak, not both of them. It seems I can’t see the meaning of ‘emerge’. Or is it ‘we’? I’d like to know the meaning of ‘we will emerge’ in the following context. **What’s the true meaning of the part?**

> ”It was carefully planned. My father led me and Winky up to the Top Box early in the day. Winky was to say that she was saving a seat for my father. I was to sit there, invisible. When everyone had left the box, **we would emerge.** Winky would appear to be alone. Nobody would ever know. (*Harry Potter 4* [US Version]: p.686)[Bold font is mine]

**N.B.:** The speaker was a wanted person. He is confessing the truth after arrested

**N.B.2:** He went watching the World Cup of a magical sport with his father and a servant called Winky while at large.

**N.B.3:** The speaker was wearing his Invisibility Cloak, but Winky wasn’t.

### Why am I asking?

A dictionary defines *emerge* as 1-3. Italicized lines are my thought.

> 1. to come out of something or out from behind something

*Likely, but wait a sec, the sentence says ‘we’, not ‘I’.*

> 1. to stop being involved in a difficult situation or period of time

*Likely, but I don’t know for sure what the whole sentence means. Does it mean, by any chance, everyone’s leaving the box means their emerging from the difficult situation?*

> 1. to become known

*Impossible*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important phrase:

> *When everyone had left the box*, we would emerge.

They were going to the "Top Box". After everyone had left, only then, would they leave the Box. "Emerge" has the meaning that you stated, "to come out of something."

It says "we" because both him and Winky is going to come out of the Box, not Winky or him alone. But Winky will appear to be alone, because the speaker *was under his invisibility cloak*

That's the reason the speaker said:

> When everyone had left the box, we would emerge. Winky would appear to be alone. *Nobody would ever know*